# Redirect 301 htaccess only work with slash Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, laravel-4

I have  a problem with my redirection.

i wanna **redirect domain.ir to domain.com** ok all fine but when

*I wanna **all request** from domain.ir redirect to domain.com only work when i finish urls with slash*

domain.ir/wiki/ ---> domain.com/wiki

but

domain.ir/wiki  ---> domain.com/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.digibaj.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digibaj.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.digibaj.ir$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digibaj.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^digibaj.ir$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digibaj.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[Digibaj.com](http://digibaj.com)

Any idea?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-factor and reorder your rules like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.digibaj\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?digibaj\.ir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digibaj.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes for non-directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: But Why digibaj.ir/wiki redirect to digibaj.com ?!